# Mapping DataFrame column with other DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, object

I have a CSV file with players history ranks since the beginning of 2010 up to 2018. the ranking is refreshing each week so there are 54 x 8 rankings in one file. There are columns like date, rank position, player id and points. Player id is a specific number individual for each player. I do have a second csv with player id, player name, player surname. I want to map player id in the first data frame with name and surname of a player form the second csv.

I have just creat dict form second csv with  `<to_dict`> I was trying to map this with `<.map(dict1)>` and with `<from_dict>` but without success.

```py
data_players = pd.read_csv(filepath, engine="python", sep=";", 
keep_default_na=False)
data_rank = pd.read_csv(filepath2, engine="python", sep=",", 
keep_default_na=False)

data_players = data_players.set_index('player_id')
dict1 = data_players.to_dict('index')
data_rank['player'] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
```

My data looks like this

```
ranking_date     int64
rank             int64
points          object
player          object
dtype: object

        ranking_date  rank points                      player
player
103819      20100104     1  10550    {'name_list': 'Federer'}
104745      20100104     2   9205      {'name_list': 'Nadal'}
104925      20100104     3   8310   {'name_list': 'Djokovic'}
104918      20100104     4   7030     {'name_list': 'Murray'}
105223      20100104     5   6785  {'name_list': 'Del Potro'}
```

I expect to find the solution for this, I think that this is simple but I am just learning python.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use dict, use here

```
Df= data_players.merge(data_rank,left_on=“player_id”, right_on=“player_id”)
```